# how to get multiple items/users by search in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, search, laravel-5

i am working on search module in laravel.. when i submit a keyword in search input at the result i get only one record.. but i have multiple user on a single name. how to get multiple users on same name.. i tried this

**Controller**

```
class SearchController extends Controller
{
    public function find(Request $request)
    {
    $search=$request->input('search-input');


    $getUser = User::join('personalinfos', 'users.id', '=', 'personalinfos.user_id')->where('users.firstName', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
        ->orWhere('users.lastName', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')->get();


    return view('pages/search-users',compact('getUser'));


    }
}
```

**Form**

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right hidden-sm" id="search-form" action="{{url('/find')}}" method="get">
      {{  csrf_field() }}
      <div class="form-group">
        <i class="icon ion-android-search"></i>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search-input" name="search-input"  placeholder="Search friends, photos, videos">
      </div>
    </form>
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('find', 'SearchController@find');
```

Comment: Does every user have personalinfos?

Comment: I am not sure what are you doing? FIrst of all you are running two queries and you are replacing result of first query with second one then whats the point of having first query at all :))

Comment: @Autista_z yes every user have

Comment: What is the DDL of your personalinfos ?

Comment: @Learner sorry by mistake.. review it again i update it

Comment: Try out my answer to see where is the problem

Comment: Edited the answer, tryout to see if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are trying to do this:

```
$getUser = User::join('personalinfos AS pi', 'users.id', '=', 'pi.user_id')
               ->where('users.firstName', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
               ->orWhere('users.lastName', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
               ->select('users.firstName','users.lastName')
               ->get();
```

If it still returns only one user, that means your condition:

```
users.id = pi.user_id
```

is only true for that user.

To make sure, run this:

```
$getUser = User::where('firstName', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
                   ->orWhere('lastName', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
                   ->select('firstName','lastName')
                   ->get();
```

This last one must return more than one user if you have more than one user of same name in your database.

Good luck!

Comment: the last query return multiple users but i want to join the Personalinfo table also.. how would be possible return multiple users and both tables data

Comment: Problem is `users.id = pi.user_id` condition, you need to have various `user_id` representing various users in users table. I am guessing that you are using only ONE user_id in your personalinfo table. Use multiple user_id so that every user in users table can have one row in personalinfo table.